# Can't write/read with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

When i write like this

```
std::fstream file ("data.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
if (!file)
{
    std::cerr << "Error";
    exit(1);
}
```

I receive "Error". When i rewrite the whole thing like this

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("data.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
if (!file)
{
    std::cerr << "Error";
    exit(1);
}
```

data.dat is being created, and i manage to write and read. Am doing this on VS 2013, in addition to that i tried compiling on 6.0 version and both ways have worked. I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: @marsh What's the difference?

Comment: @marsh How will that prevent the file from being created?

Comment: Both snippets are equivalent. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @zenith, yes, you're right. I just tried compiling again, but both methods gave the same error. Am i doing a mistake in here? I have included all the necessary headers. Also this works if i use ifstream for input and ofstream for output, i was trying fstream for the first time. May you have any guesses on which parts should i look closer at?

Comment: I have a small theory, using ios::in even with the bitwise OR requires the file being already created? Is that the problem here?

Comment: Okay, i tried some possible pairs of streams and ios::in/outs and looks like that was the problem. When data.dat already existed, i had no problem with reading/writing using both ways. Guess this question may be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because you instructed `fstream` to open the file for reading as well. If the file does not exist flags `in | out` will give you an error. Try it with only `out` and it should work. If you want to do write and read on a file that does not exist you need an extra flag, either append (`app`) or truncate (`trunc`)

Comment: It does not. In the comments, user3002386 mentions that both methods give an error.

Comment: Then the question is broken and should either be fixed or deleted.

Comment: Yup, it's pretty much like that. The second example worked, because the file was already created, and i didn't think it would matter at that time :) Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: @A Hernandez, But i got another question, why does it still work on VS 6.0? Even without having the file created, i can use ios::in and everything works. How come so?